Error al instalar .net framework 4.8 dice que ya existe pero no
Tengo un servidor con windows server 2019 standar, trato de abrir el IIS pero me da este error

Después intento instalar la versión 4.8 y me dice lo siguiente

y al tratar de abrir el administrador del servidor o el powershell no abre nada.
Creo que ya tiene una versión de framework, pero algo en su registro debe estar mal, y es raro que no pueda abrir el administrador del servidor.
EDIT: Tratando con la versión 4.0 me da el mismo error


Dice que instales una versión específica, la 4.0.... no la 4.8. Prueba con este instalador https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851 o este https://dotnet.microsoft.com/es-es/download/dotnet-framework/net40 (cualquiera de la derecha)

Me da el mismo error, amigo

Que extraño. Parece un problema complicado. Mira estos links y dinos si alguno te sirve o si encuentras otra solución https://serverfault.com/q/205229 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1320701/how-to-install-net-framework-4-0-030319-runtime-on https://answers.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/forum/all/error-net-framework-initialization-v4030319/dca978f8-626f-49bb-b321-8e5df51602f2 como último recurso puedes hacer una instalación limpia o restablecer el sistema operativo

Gracias amigo, pareciera que ya funciona o al menos ya las aplicaciones ahora sí lo toman, seguiré haciendo una pruebas solo para confirmar que funcioné correctamente
